# Node 'output' does not exist in model 'file:///android_asset/myoutput_graph.pb'

Tags: tensorflow

I compiled TensorFlow Mobile demo in Android Studio and reported anomalies when using my retrained model.

Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Node 'output' does not exist in model
>   'file:///android_asset/myoutput_graph.pb' which I trained from a standard Tensorflow "inception-2015-12-05.tgz".

Comment: Haha, I solved it ， 
Execute the following script:                                                                          python tensorflow\tensorflow\python\tools\strip_unused.py                                  --input_graph=..\inception_model\retrain\myoutput_graph.pb                        --output_graph= ..\inception_model\retrain\ my_tfm_output_graph.pb        --input_node_names=”Mul”                                                                          --output_node_names="final_result"                                                                  --input_binary=true

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same with the mobilenet_v1_0.50_224 model and I have the same error. Have you an idea on how to find the names of input and output nodes to be fed to strip_unused parameters? Thanks

Comment: Actually, it seems that changing the value of the OUTPUT_NAME variable in ClassifierActivity.java (around line #72) and setting to "final_result" should be enough, provided that you are using the TF Classifier demo app. Of course you also have to change the values of MODEL_FILE and LABEL_FILE, that I think you have already done.

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you said.about “strip_unused parameters”， I got all the node names via "graph.get_all_ops ..." by using python to load the network model (xx.pb) and then looked up the names of these nodes based on Tensorboard。